# unable to publish Path waypoints for pure pursuit

Tags: python, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are the initial line of my rospy code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node('path_for_control', anonymous=True)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('path', Path, queue_size=10)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)  # small amount on purpose (20m in 20 sec)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    Trajectory()
    rate.sleep()
```

This is the launch file in which is being used:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="pure_pursuit" name="pure_pursuit" type="pure_pursuit" />
    <node pkg="pure_pursuit" name="waypoint_publisher" type="control_listpath.py" />
</launch>
```

And this is the error while launching the launch file using
`roslaunch pure_pursuit pure_pursuit.launch`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/krush/SDC/src/pure_pursuit/src/control_listpath.py", line 148, in <module>
pub = rospy.Publisher('path', Path, queue_size=10)
 File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 842, in __init__
super(Publisher, self).__init__(name, data_class, Registration.PUB)
 File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 142, in __init__
 raise ValueError("data_class [%s] is not a class"%data_class) 
 ValueError: data_class [<function Path at 0x7f636ecb6280>] is not a class
```

---

Edit:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import math

import numpy as np
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from nav_msgs.msg import Path

def Path():
    # path = [(2.0, 0.0), (4.0, 0.0), (6.0, 0.0), (8.0, 0.0), (10.0, 0.0), (13.0, 0.0), (16.0, 1.5), (20.0, 2.5)]
    global i
    point_X, point_Y = path[i]
    i += 1

    if i == 8:
        i = 0

    pitch = 0
    roll = 0
    carPosX, carPosY = (0.0, 0.0)
    track = Path()
    track.header.frame_id = "base_link"
    track.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    # for point_X, point_Y in path:
    # yaw = math.atan((point_Y - carPosY)/(point_X - carPosX))
    # print(yaw)

    dir_vec = np.array([point_X - carPosX, point_Y - carPosY])
    axis = np.array([1.0, 0.0])

    # #do dot product between them
    cos_theta = np.dot(dir_vec, axis) / (np.sqrt((point_X - carPosX) ** 2 + (point_Y - carPosY) ** 2))
    yaw = math.acos(_cos_theta)

    qx = np.sin(roll/2) * np.cos(pitch/2) * np.cos(yaw/2) - np.cos(roll/2) * np.sin(pitch/2) * np.sin(yaw/2)
    qy = np.cos(roll/2) * np.sin(pitch/2) * np.cos(yaw/2) + np.sin(roll/2) * np.cos(pitch/2) * np.sin(yaw/2)
    qz = np.cos(roll/2) * np.cos(pitch/2) * np.sin(yaw/2) - np.sin(roll/2) * np.sin(pitch/2) * np.cos(yaw/2)
    qw = np.cos(roll/2) * np.cos(pitch/2) * np.cos(yaw/2) + np.sin(roll/2) * np.sin(pitch/2) * np.sin(yaw/2)

    pose = PoseStamped()

    pose.pose.position.x = point_X
    pose.pose.position.y = point_Y
    pose.pose.position.z = 0.0
    pose.pose.orientation.x = qx
    pose.pose.orientation.y = qy
    pose.pose.orientation.z = qz
    pose.pose.orientation.w = qw
    track.poses.append(pose)

    pub.publish(track)

    carPosX, carPosY = point_X, point_Y


def interm(k=0):
    path = [
        (2.0, 0.0),
        (4.0, 0.0),
        (6.0, 0.0),
        (8.0, 0.0),
        (10.0, 0.0),
        (13.0, 0.0),
        (16.0, 1.5),
        (20.0, 2.5),
    ]
    point_X, point_Y = path[k]
    path(point_X, point_Y)

    # k = path.index((point_X, point_Y))
    print(k)
    if k < 8:
        k += 1
    else:
        k = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node('path_for_control', anonymous=True)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('path', Path, queue_size=10)
    # pub = rospy.Publisher('path_segment', PoseStamped, queue_size = 1)
    # k = 0
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)  # small amount on purpose (20m in 20 sec)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        Path()
        rate.sleep()
    # rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373645/unable-to-publish-path-waypoints-for-pure-pursuit/) by [krushnal](https://answers.ros.org/users/71675/krushnal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The second argument to the [`rospy.Publisher` constructor](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Publisher-class.html) is `data_class` which the docs say should be a *message class for serialization*. So you need to provide a ROS message class. From the provided code snippet it's impossible for us to tell what `Path` is (seems like a function defined elsewhere in the Python code), but whatever it is it is not the right type of object. If you look at the [rospy Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber) you'll see they have a line like:

```
from std_msgs.msg import String
```

Then in their publisher constructor

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
```

This is an example of how to import a ROS message class and use as the `data_class` argument in the `Publisher` constructor. You'll need to do something similar.

**UPDATE:**

@krushnal, now that all of your code has been added to the original question, the issue is exactly as I described in the comments below. This line

```
from nav_msgs.msg import Path
```

defines a variable `Path` that is a ROS message class in the global namespace. Then, the very next line, you have

```
def Path():
```

which also creates a variable `Path` in the global namespace, but this one is a function. The issue you're seeing is because this second variable overwrites the import variable from above. Hence the error I highlighted below:

```
ValueError: data_class [<function Path at 0x7f636ecb6280>] is not a class
```

Which tells you the argument that you've provided for `data_class` is a function called `Path` with some memory address. It is *not* the ROS message class that it needs to be. You either need to rename this `Path` function or change how you import the ROS message. For example, you could simply `import nav_msgs.msg` module and then access the `Path` class in that module's namespace. E.g., `nav_msgs.msg.Path`

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2021-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krushnal](https://answers.ros.org/users/71675/krushnal/) on 2021-03-10**:
Path is of the type nav_msgs/Path which I have imported at the top using `from nav_msgs.msg import Path`

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-03-10**:
This part of your error message seems to indicate otherwise:

```
ValueError: data_class [<function Path at 0x7f636ecb6280>] is not a class
```

Perhaps updating your question to provide the full Python code would better help diagnose the specific issue. It's possible, for example, that even though you've imported a `Path` message that somewhere else the variable `Path` is being redefined.

**Comment by [krushnal](https://answers.ros.org/users/71675/krushnal/) on 2021-03-10**:
i have added my code as an answer

**Comment by [krushnal](https://answers.ros.org/users/71675/krushnal/) on 2021-03-10**:
thanks a lot!!!! that solved the problem.... i changed the Path() function name to something else

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-03-11**:
Glad you were able to get things sorted!